# Have to login twice to access to other page in PHP

Tags: php

I am building a admin login page for my site. I am sure what's wrong with my script, but I have to login twice to able to redirect to the admin home page. Can anybody help me what I am doing wrong or am I missing something? 
Also, I tried it in localhost and the script worked fine, only need to login once. After I put it in my host, I have to login twice.
Thank you.

```
<?php 
session_start(); 
include_once("../config.php");
if(isset($_SESSION['name'])) {
    header('location:viewallitems.php');
}?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">

<head>
     <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
     <title>Login</title>
     <link href="style.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>

<body>
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
$errors = array();
$required = array('email','pword');
foreach($required as $fieldname) {
    if(!isset($_POST[$fieldname]) || empty($_POST[$fieldname])) {
        $errors[]= "The <strong> {$fieldname} </strong> was left blank";
    }
}//End: foreach
if(empty($errors)) {
    $email = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli,$_POST['email']);
    $pword = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli,$_POST['pword']);
    $hash_pw = $pword;

    $query = "SELECT CONCAT_WS(' ', first_name, last_name) 
              AS name
              FROM admin
              WHERE email='$email'
              AND pword='$hash_pw'
              LIMIT 1";
    $result = mysqli_query($mysqli,$query) or die(mysqli_error());
    if(mysqli_num_rows($result) == 1) {
        while($rows = mysqli_fetch_array($result,MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
            $_SESSION['name'] = $rows['name'];
            header('location: viewallitems.php');
        }
    } else {
        $errors[] = "The email or password do not match those on file.";
    }
}

}//End if($_POST['submit'])
else {
    if(isset($_GET['stat']) && $_GET['stat'] == 1) {
        $message = "<ul><li>You are now logged out.</li></ul>";
    }
}
?>
    <div id="wrapper">
    <div class="bg"><a href="../index.html" target="_blank"><img src="../images/logo.png" /></a></div>
    <h1>Login To Admin Panel</h1>
        <?php if(!empty($errors)) {
            echo "<ul>";
            foreach($errors as $error) {
                echo "<li>{$error}</li>";
            }
            echo "</ul>";
        }?>

        <?php if(isset($message)) echo $message;?>
        <form action="" method="post">
            <center><img src="../images/avatar.png"></center>
            <p>
                <label for="email">Email:</label>
                <input type="text" size="35" placeholder="Enter Email" name="email"/>
            </p>

            <p>
                <label for="password">Password:</label>
                <input type="password" size="35" placeholder="Enter Password" name="pword" />
            </p>

            <p>
                <input class="blue" type="submit" name="submit" value="LOG IN" />
            </p>
        </form>
        <div class='login'>
            <a href="#">Login</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. use ob_start();
2. remove php in front of fourth line.
3. change doctype to HTML5 doctype
4. Re position your HTML(starting from line 7) to new postion after all that php.that might be hindering header() function. and anyways it's always good to have all in one place.

newly, added :

5. free up result memory with  mysql_free_result($result)

Comment: Wow, thank you so much. I rearranged like you said, it worked perfectly.

Comment: @RickNg nice to hear that u got things working. added one more point for you.

Comment: Thanks for helping me!

Answer (score 0):

When you redirect to viewallitems.php, check the url in the browser, do you use www. infront of your domain when loggin in, then redirect it to non-www ? Cause php treat www.yourdomain.com/viewallitems.php and yourdomain.com/viewallitems.php as two different domain, therefore the session is not shared. if you log in at www.yourdomain.com/login.php, try to go to www.yourdomain.com/viewallitems.php, I don't think you will need to log in again.

If that is the problem in your case, there are several solutions that I can think of:

1.Rewrite mode using .htaccess file so that all page in your website will be redirected to www. version or the non-www version of your domain. This way when you enter yourdomain.com/login.php, it will be redirected automatically to www.yourdomain.com/login.php

.htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^yourdomain.com$
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.yourdomain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

2.There is actually a function in php to share session called **session_name** and **session_set_cookie_params**. Check the documentation below:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-name.php

http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-set-cookie-params.php

It used to work, then it does not work. I am not too sure now, whether they fix this issue or not.

3.Set session for both domain www.yourdomain.com version and non-www.yourdomain.com version.

I would prefer using the first option as it limits the possibilities of the browser to treat your website as two different domains.

Comment: Thank you so much. Yes, I am worry about that too, because without login and if someone knows the path then they can easy access to viewallitems page. Any idea how can I fix this issue?

Comment: Please check my editted answer above, sorry if my explanation is not very clear. Feel free to ask me and I will try my best to elaborate my answers.

Comment: Thanks so much. I will give a try your suggestion.